# Is .NET Object Creation "ex nihilo"?

Tags: .net

I was reading about [prototype-based](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based) languages and this doubt comes into my mind:

Is .NET Object Creation *ex nihilo* ("from nothing") and so allow new objects to be created from scratch? Or, instead, is .NET object creation based on cloning from an existing object (i.e. [Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx)) as the cloning prototype for new object creations?

Comment: +1 for uncommon and interesting question

Comment: @RedFilter: What does bitter Latin taste or sound like?

Comment: @BoltClock - like the _Latin_ used on _streets_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most basic objects in .Net have no user-wise data, only some internal platform's information about their type and in-memory location of their actual data. From the user's (developer's) point of view, they 'just exist' and they only differ in their 'identity'. Their class cannot be extended in any way. I do not see any point in cloning anything.

More complicated objects are derived from something, and ultimately are derived from the base object. There is no copy-construction and no deep-copying semantics in .Net, so at the level of non-basic objects, there still is no point in cloning anything.

At the level of metadata, each object carries information about what class(es) does it belong to. The metainformation is shared, and all objects of the same class just point to the shared metainformation. Still no point in cloning anything.

Thus, I'd be very surprised if the object creation was done in a prototype-cloning fashion. I do not know with absolute certainity, but I bet that it is not. I'm alsmost sure that object creation is just allocation of small memory block and maybe setting a few pointers inside its header.

It certainly is verifiable if someone **ngen**s some code and disassembles it to see how new() operator works :)

Comment: "They just are" makes no sense.  All object in .NET have data--references reference memory and an empty struct has a size of 1...

Comment: You are right, the wording was quite odd. I'll write it differently

Answer (score 2):

C# is not prototype based. You dont need an instance of an existing object to create a new one, nor is it possible to 'extend' an object like javascript can.

So in principle, all objects are created ex nihilo.